# Regex to match 1 to 10 digit number with any number of decimal Places

Tags: regex

I want a regex to match cost.

Valid cost-

```
1.1234455

12.434343

123.3333
..
```

upto 10 digits maximum..

and invalid is

```
0.545454

000.5435435
```

Comment: Why is `0.545454` invalid? Are integers like `123` allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex that will match any cost except those that have all zeros before the floating point

```
(?!0+\.)\d+\.\d+
```

http://regex101.com/r/pQ4kB3